# How can I find 2 unknowns when they are in the same equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

So I have a question like this.

*Given that $x + 1/y = 3/2$ and $y + 1/x = 1/6$, what is the value of $x / y$?*

So basically I'm trying to get $x$ and $y$ on their own but I don't know how to because they are in both equations. I can't get my head around it. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: The tag 'abstract-algebra' does not mean what you think it means; it is rather a much more complex topic studied in university ([Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebra)).

Comment: Oh I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy, $x+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{3}{2}$ and $y+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{6}$

So, $xy+1=\frac{3y}{2}$ and $xy+1=\frac{x}{6}$ , subtracting we get, $\frac{3y}{2}=\frac{x}{6}\implies \frac{x}{y}=9$

Comment: How did you get xy + 1?

Comment: I have added them! Do you know about algebraic addition of fractions? See https://www.mathsisfun.com/fractions_addition.html